# Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale when using geom_mosaic

Tags: r

i'm trying to create a mosaic chart using geom_mosaic function (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmosaic/vignettes/ggmosaic.html).

my code is as follows:

```
library(readxl)
library(HH)
library(tidyverse) 
library(ggmosaic)

# read excel file
cchs <- read_excel("test.xlsx", sheet=2)

#plot mosaic
ggplot(data = cchs) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(Role,Workers_Involvement), fill=Workers_Involvement)) +  xlab("Type of Smoker") + ylab("Relative Frequency") +
  labs(fill = "Frequency", title='Worker involvement')
```

test.xlsx file looks like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I31W3.png)

Comment: Hi - please consider posting your data structure instead of an image so that we can recreate the error, for instance using `dput(cchs)`- images and the line `cchs <- read_excel("test.xlsx", sheet=2)` are not useful in this context

Comment: As for what @jpsmith said- when you want great answers quickly, it's important to make your issue reproducible. That being said, it's pretty likely that that the values in the columns `Role` and `Workers_Involvement` are not interpreted as factors. You have to make sure the data types are correct before this will work.

Comment: Hi epy, to get a aggod answer to your question, i advise to give a MRE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example